# Flutter type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<String>'

Tags: flutter

I have this widget

```
StreamBuilder(
        stream:
            FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('HouseDetails').snapshots(),
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
          if (!snapshot.hasData) {
            return Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            );
          }
          return Expanded(
            child: ListView(
              children: snapshot.data.docs.map<Widget>((document) {
                return _buildHouse(context, document);
              }).toList(),
              physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
            ),
          );
        });
```

Now the `_buildHouse` builds a basic screen which has an onTap functionality. I am passing the `QueryDocumentSnapshot` `document` to another screen using `MaterialPageRoute`.

```
 onTap: () {
        Navigator.push(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (_) => DetailsScreen(house: document),
          ),
        );
      },
```

the line   `builder: (_) => DetailsScreen(house: document),` throws the error

```
The following _TypeError was thrown building DetailsScreen(dirty, state: _DetailsScreenState#cc47a):
I/flutter ( 5479): type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<String>'
I/flutter ( 5479): The relevant error-causing widget was:
 I/flutter ( 5479):   DetailsScreen
```

What goes wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

I just had to use `.map<String>((e)=>e.toString()).toList()` inside the DetailsScreen class where the variables of the type `List<String>` .

Answer (score 0):

I always got that error when setting a list like this:
`List testList;`

Often it's solved by just doing
`List testList = [];`
or
`List testList = new List;`

Comment: This happens as you have not initialized your list yet.